# incomplete results by mongoDB aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have a mongo collection whose sample structure is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57835fd76898868d7d110228"),
    "name" : "Family Vision Clinic - Doctors of Optometry",
    "website" : "familyvisionclinic.ca",
    "phone" : null,
    "address" : {
        "street" : "650 Portland St",
        "city" : "Dartmouth",
        "state" : "NOVA SCOTIA",
        "zip" : "B2W6A",
        "country" : "Canada"
    },
    "profile_url" : "https://www.haha.org",

}
```

I want to group all entries by **country**

Here's what i have tried

```
db.subset.aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$address" },
{ "$group":{"_id": "$address.country","count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

But this is giving me incomplete results. I mean many entries have **United States** as their country as I can see through eyeballing the data while after running this query I get no entry with United States as country

USA entry

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57835fd76898868d7d110226"),
    "name" : "Doctors of Optometry",
    "website" : "eyedoctorandglasses.com",
    "phone" : null,
    "address" : {
        "street" : "4505 Sepulveda Blvd",
        "city" : "Torrance",
        "state" : "CA",
        "zip" : "90505",
        "country" : "United States"
    },
    "profile_url" : "https://www.haha2.org",
    "id" : "3330542"
}
```

Comment: could you add USA example documnet?

Comment: it's done, the problem was with Robomongo - mongo client which i was using, when i ran the same query in mongo terminal, it worked

Comment: Its working fine with Robomongo - mongo client and mongo terminal.

Comment: it's not working for me in robomongo(0.9.0 RC9), it also depends upon the amount of data you are applying this query. How can you be certain on robomongo even when you don't have the similar amount of data, Moreover for me it was working fine for me  on mongochef

Comment: address is not an array field. Why is there a need to use `$unwind`?

Comment: yaa, don't need unwind
this would also work db.subset.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$address.country", count : {$sum : 1}}}])